# error "derivs is larger than length of x" in b-splines used in lmer

Tags: r, lme4

I use `Rstudio`. According to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135694/using-b-splines-within-a-linear-mixed-effects-model-in-r I would like to add so-called b-splines into my lmer model:

```
degree<- 3
fit<- lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ bs(poly(Voltage, degree)) + bs(poly(Voltage, degree) | Serial_number),data = APD))
```

but this results in

```
Error in splineDesign(Aknots, x, ord) : 
  length of 'derivs' is larger than length of 'x'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(poly(Voltage, 3), Serial_number) :
  ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
2: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

What does that mean? When I use instead

```
summary(fit<- lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ (poly(bs(Voltage), degree)) + (poly(Voltage, degree) | Serial_number), data = APD))
```

then this results in

```
Error in poly(dots[[i]], degree, raw = raw, simple = raw) : 
  'degree' must be less than number of unique points
```

Going down to `degree=0` yields

```
Error in poly(dots[[1L]], degree, raw = raw, simple = raw && nd > 1) : 
  'degree' must be at least 1
```

How can I add b-splines into lmer?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after using `scale(VAR)` in a regression. When I scaled the variable in a previous step with:

```
mutate(CVAR=scale(VAR, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
```

`ggpredict` gave a correct estimate.

Comment: In R the convention is to use spaces around "=" when providing values for arguments